# Problems configuring External List on Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, bcs, external-content-type

I have created a new database on MS SQL SERVER SHAREPOINT instace that contains two simple tables.

Then I tried to link values defined in these tables by implementing External Content Types using Sharepoint Designer.

The process seems to worked without any errors but now, when I try to access the External List based on this contents I receive the error:

> Cannot connect to the LobSystem
>   (External System)

I check all permissions on new database, Business Data Connectivity Service, etc. but I didn't found a solution to this.

Do you have any suggestions what could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the cause of my problem.

I enabled logging of `Business Connectivity Services in Monitor` -> `Diagnostic Logging` and I found the exception:

> Could not open connection using 'data
>   source=XXXXXXXXX\SHAREPOINT;initial
>   catalog=XXXXX;integrated
>   security=SSPI;pooling=true;persist
>   security info=false' in App Domain
>   '/LM/W3SVC/210338692/ROOT-1-129314031335556640'.
>   The full exception text is: Cannot
>   open database "XXXXX" requested by the
>   login. The login failed.  Login failed
>   for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

At this point I solved by explicit add the account 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' to the database of external data.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials passed to the database are configurable.

[Business Data Connectivity Service Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms566523.aspx)

It sounds as if you were using RevertToSelf and a Standalone Sharepoint installation (non farm)

As you are using SharePoint Foundation unfortunately the Secure Store service is not available.

Comment: Yes, correct. I am using Standalone installation with Sharepoint Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this using WCF instead SQL in the External Content Type Connection.

In this link, use a WCF Generator with SQL to create de WCF, tehn you can use it in SharePoint and workaround the problem.

http://swainman.spaces.live.com/