# SharePoint 2013 error with external list connecting to LobSystem

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I created the ECT with a Custom Impersonated ID so it is connecting to the SQL Database with a specific ID and PW for the SQL DB not through windows Authentication. I created the External list successfully but when trying to view the App it gives this error: `

> Cannot connect to the LobSystem (External System). Reason: 'A
>   network-related or instance -specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)'
>   `

I found this link that was three years ago, [Problems configuring External List on Sharepoint Foundation 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6220/problems-configuring-external-list-on-sharepoint-foundation-2010/110844?noredirect=1#comment109705_110844) and I think it might be similar, but the only solution I took from it was modifying the SQL server.

I haven't turned on the diagnostics because I am working with a team that has the access to Central Administration. I was hoping you might have some experience to share with this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the Uls Logs(may be enable the verbos for BCS) and also check the Application logs on sharepoint server as well as on the SQL server.

- Most common reason for not being able to get to the database, apart
  from someone forgetting to plug it into the network or switch it on,
  is permissions. And usually the database is SQL Server and [we don't
  have permissions set up in SQL Server](http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/message.aspx?name=Cannot-connect-to-the-LobSystem-External-System)
- add network service user in Database
- if you are using Secure store service account to connect to LOB system then setting your credential there would work
- [refer](http://blog.rafelo.com/2010/02/13/bcs-external-list-error-%E2%80%93-cannot-connect-to-the-lobsystems-external-system/)

Comment: I did create a Secure Store Service custom account to allow the ECT to get connected. The SQL Server has an account ID an password that is used on the SSS custom account. I can access the SQL Server through Microsoft Access. I have created an external list based on the ECT, but when I click to view the list on SharePoint the page loads and a green ball with green squares around it looks like a buffering connection. After about two minutes I receive the error in my first post in place of the green ball.